# How to show SignIn with Google dialog from bottom sheet in Android?

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to show sign-in with google dialog from bottom sheet like Pinterest as shown in image below.[image]

As per documentation we don't have choice to open it as bottom sheet dialog, any idea how to manage this behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the Google 'one-tap' sign-in. For more information see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials).